# Adding Column to list of CSVs in R

Tags: r, list, csv

I'm working on a project where I have a list of csv files called 'all_csvs' and a list of dates (that correspond to the date of the csv file) called 'dates'.  They both have the same length (since date is derived from the individual csv title name).  I want to add a column for each csv so that the date stored in the 'dates' list is repeated over every row in the corresponding csv.

The data layout is more-or-less.

```
all_csvs = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
dates = ['date1', 'date2']
```

I would like to make a column for each csv file where the date is added. So for file1.csv, we would add a column for which every value in that column is date1. (and continue that pattern over every csv file)

Any direction would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that reads in a csv file and adds as column with a single value to it. It's then easily applied to all filename + date pairs using `mapply`.

```
all_csvs <- c('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv')
dates <- c('date1', 'date2', 'date3')

add_date_to_csv <- function(csv, date) {
  data <- read.csv(csv)
  data$date <- date
  write.csv(data, csv, row.names=FALSE)
}

mapply(add_date_to_csv, all_csvs, dates)
```

Note that this makes changes to the original files, so it's safest to keep a backup (or changing the output path) while testing it.

Comment: I get this error message when I try to apply that function to my lists:                        Error in file == "" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: @BenjaminBlackburn There was a typo. The second argument of write.csv() should be csv, not file. See the updated answer.